# NodeJS / Google Cloud Function — CSRF-verification failed response from server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, http-referer

I get a "CSRF-verification failed" response from the server.

I don't get why tho.
I'm trying both using Google Cloud Function and running the code on my own machine.

**Error Reponse**

CSRF-verification failed. Try again.

**Code**

```
const axios = require('axios')
const to = require('await-to-js').default

const getAPI = () => {

    // basic auth
    const auth = {
        username: "API USER",
        password: "API PASSWORD"
    }

    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "https://sandbox.billogram.com/api/v2/invoice",
        auth,
        headers: {
            Referer: "http://localhost:3000/"
        }
    })
    return instance
}

const createInvoice = async () => {
    const api = getAPI()
    const [err, res] = await to(
        api.post('invoice', {
            "items": [
                {
                    "description": "Item 1",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "unit_price": 100
                }
            ],
            "currency": "SEK",
            "customer": {
                "first_name": "John",
                "last_name": "Doe",
                "email": "john.doe@example.com",
                "phone": "555-555-5555"
            }
        })
    )
    if (err) return console.log('ERR', err.message, err.response.data)
    console.log(res.data)
}

createInvoice()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```

**Question**

- Can you try to explain how come?
- Also how to find the correct Referer from Google Cloud and local development machine?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try accessing the same page in another browser or in an incognito window. This may help identify if the issue is related to your browser settings or cache
Refresh the page: Sometimes, refreshing the page can resolve the issue if the error is temporary or due to a network issue.
Clear your browser cache: Clearing your browser cache may help resolve the issue if it is related to a stale or incorrect browser cache.
Check if any extensions are caused with your HTTP Referrer
Disable all of your extensions in your web browser temporarily in order to see if one of them is causing the issue.

Comment: Usually a good idea to start/verify with cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was me who relied on ChatGPT code too much.
The API was updated and the API endpoint had been changed.